# Headless UI Transition not working with Dialog

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I'm using nextjs 13 with headless ui. The transition effect only works when it leaves and not when it enters. Is this a bug with their code or am I doing something wrong? Here is my code:

```
"use client";
import { Dialog, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { RootState } from "@/redux/store";
import { setShowModal } from "@/redux/slices/modalSlice";
import { Fragment } from "react";

function Modal() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const modal = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.modal.value);

  return (
    <Transition
      appear={true}
      as={Fragment}
      show={modal}
      enter="transition-all duration-1000 ease-in-out"
      enterFrom="opacity-0"
      enterTo="opacity-100"
      leave="transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
      leaveFrom="opacity-100"
      leaveTo="opacity-0"
    >
      <Dialog
        onClose={() => dispatch(setShowModal(false))}
        className={`relative z-50`}
      >
        <div
          className={`fixed inset-0 flex items-center justify-center bg-slate-900/80 p-4 text-white`}
        >
          <Dialog.Panel>
            <Dialog.Title>Deactivate account</Dialog.Title>
            <Dialog.Description>
              This will permanently deactivate your account
            </Dialog.Description>

            <p>
              Are you sure you want to deactivate your account? All of your data
              will be permanently removed. This action cannot be undone.
            </p>

            <button onClick={() => dispatch(setShowModal(false))}>
              Deactivate
            </button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(setShowModal(false))}>
              Cancel
            </button>
          </Dialog.Panel>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition>
  );
}

export default Modal;
```

This is me adding more details since it insists that I do.

Answer (score 0):

the headless modal transition is not functioning. The 'Transition.Child' element is primarily used to produce smooth transition effects. I looked over your code, and you forgot to include the "Transition.Child" components in your modal.You can view the complete headlessui modal example from their official website at https://headlessui.com/react/dialog in addition to the example I have added for this element.

```
<Transition.Child
  as={Fragment}
  enter="ease-out duration-300"
  enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
  enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
  leave="ease-in duration-200"
  leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
  leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
>
  Child Elements here
</Transition.Child>
```

The complete example with your modal is here.

```
    <div className="fixed inset-0 overflow-y-auto">
        <div className="flex min-h-full items-center justify-center p-4 text-center">
            <Transition.Child as={Fragment} enter="ease-out duration-300" enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
                enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100" leave="ease-in duration-200" leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
                leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95">
                <Dialog.Panel
                    className="w-full max-w-md transform overflow-hidden rounded-2xl bg-white p-6 text-left align-middle shadow-xl transition-all">
                    <Dialog.Title as="h3" className="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                        Deactivate account
                    </Dialog.Title>
                    <div className="mt-2">
                        <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                            This will permanently deactivate your account
                        </p>
                        <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                            Are you sure you want to deactivate your account? All of your data will be permanently removed. This action cannot be undone.
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="mt-4">
                        <button onClick={() => dispatch(setShowModal(false))}>
                            Deactivate
                        </button>
                        <button onClick={() => dispatch(setShowModal(false))}>
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </Dialog.Panel>
            </Transition.Child>
        </div>
    </div>
</Dialog>
```